# React, visualizing and editing a JSON object. Populating data on inputs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, forms

I have this kind of objects

```
{
  asignaturaId: 1,
  content: {
    [question_var]: {
      elements: {
        text: 'text1',
        image: 'img1.jpg'
      }
    }
    [question_var]: {
      text: 'text2',
      image: 'image2.jpg'
    }
  }
}
```

the thing that varies is the `[question_var]` part and how many objects does `content` key includes.

I want to be able to dynamically write out all the data on inputs and being able to replace the needed data.

so far I got this:

```
[...]
<FormControl>
  <InputLabel htmlFor="modulo">Asignatura ID:</InputLabel>
  <Input id="asignaturaId" name="asignaturaId" value={arrayData[0]} onChange={(e) => setAsignaturaId(e.target.value)} />
</FormControl>
  
{arrayData.map(pregunta => {
  console.log(pregunta)
  return (
    <>
    <FormControl>
       <InputLabel htmlFor="texto">Texto:</InputLabel>
       <Input id="texto" name="texto" onLoad={() => setTexto(pregunta[1].elements.text)} value={pregunta[1].elements} onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)} />
    </FormControl>
[...]
```

what I omited was, I took the object and did `Object.entries(myObject)` and assigned it to the `arrayData` array. `asignaturaId` will be just one key on every object I receive, so I can easily pass that value and change it on an input. The problem is the `content`, as it is dynamic and change too much, I find it hard to use `useEffect()` hook to populate my input with the data I receive and manipulating it in the same input without changing the other values with the same keys or straight foward, not being able to edit them at all.

I have 4 days in this problem. please help!

Edit: I am sorry about my english, if I didn't make myself clear, I want to overwrite the object, keeping the data the user doesn't update in the front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declear your json array first in your React hook Component and make sure each object should have unique key

```
const [yourJson,setYourJson] = useState({
  asignaturaId: 1,
  content: {
    [question_var1]: {
      elements: {
        text: 'text1',
        image: 'img1.jpg'
      }
    },
    [question_var2]: {
      text: 'text2',
      image: 'image2.jpg'
    }
  }
});
```

Add Setter to add new object in your json content

```
  const addNewData = (text, imgSrc) =>{
    let newIndex = Object.keys(yourJson.content).length + 1;
    let newJson = yourJson;
    newJson.content[`question_var${newIndex}`] = {
      'text': text,
      'image': imgSrc
    }
    setYourJson({...newJson})
  }
```

And in render callback use this mapping

```
<FormControl>
 {Object.keys(yourJson.content).map(key => (
       <InputLabel htmlFor="texto">{yourJson.content[key].text}</InputLabel>
       // <Input id="texto" name="texto" ....
      ))}
</FormControl>
```

Comment: Thank you! But I don't mean to push a new object, but overwrite the objects already existing, I am sorry if I didn't make myself clear; I am not native english speaker.

Comment: Also, I figured out with your help how to do it, I forgot to put the controlled var on the callback function.
Thank you very much.

Comment: weclome;) by the way i was about to giving you that solution for your requirement. if you need any help feel free to ask